# vuejs vuetify range datetime picker filtered on datatable

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I can't filtered my data on datatable using v-datetime-picker, i want to filter it but did'nt work

here is my datetime-picker element

```
<v-datetime-picker
      label="End Date"
      v-model="endDate"
      class="date-input">
      <template slot="dateIcon">
        <v-icon>mdi-calendar</v-icon>
      </template>
      <template slot="timeIcon">
        <v-icon>mdi-clock-outline</v-icon>
      </template></v-datetime-picker
    >
```

and this is also my data retunr start and end date

```
data() {
return {
  search: "",
  startDate: null,
  endDate: null,
  headers: [
    { text: "Date", value: "createdAt" },
  ],
  users: [],
  invalidDates: false,
};
```

},

i've make function in computed like this

```
computed: {
filteredItems() {
  if (!this.startDate || !this.endDate || this.invalidDates) {
    return this.users;
  }

  const start = new Date(this.startDate);
  const end = new Date(this.endDate);

  return this.users.filter((user) => {
    const itemDate = new Date(user.createdAt);
    return itemDate >= start && itemDate <= end;
  });
},
```

},

and my method and other function

```
    methods: {
    getData() {
      const URL = "http://localhost:8080/orders";
      axios.get(URL).then((res) => {
        this.users = res.data.data;
        this.users.forEach((user) => {
          user.createdAt = moment(user.createdAt)
            .utcOffset("+0700")
            .toDate()
            .toISOString();

          user.updatedAt = moment(user.updatedAt)
            .utcOffset("+0700")
            .toDate()
            .toISOString();
        });
      });
    },

    validateDates() {
      this.invalidDates = false;
      if (this.startDate && this.endDate) {
        const startDate = new Date(this.startDate);
        const endDate = new Date(this.endDate);
        if (startDate > endDate) {
          this.invalidDates = true;
        } else {
          this.getData();
        }
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    startDate() {
      this.validateDates();
    },
    endDate() {
      this.validateDates();
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },
```

but still i can't filtered data using date range DateStart & DateEnd, im using vue js 2 cli and vuetify

Comment: You change the format of *user.createdAt* using ```moment```, So make sure that the date format getting by your **v-model** in ```<v-datetime-picker>``` is the same format with the *users.createdAt*. Check the value in by ```{{ user.createdAt }} = {{ endDate }}``` ?